# IE7 input type hidden occupies space

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a form with hidden input fields. In IE7 the layout gets shifted. The submit button is in the next line. If you select the space in between it seems there each hidden input is a blank. What can I do against this? Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F5gFg/2/).

HTML:

```
<div id="column1">
    <div id="searchform">
        <form action="/index.php?id=17" method="post" name="searchform01">
            <input type="text" name="tx_indexedsearch[sword]" value="Suchbegriff" class="searchform-input" onfocus="clearText(this)" onblur="clearText(this)" />
            <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[_sections]" class="hidden-inputs" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[_freeIndexUid]" id="tx_indexedsearch_freeIndexUid" class="hidden-inputs" value="_" />
            <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[pointer]" id="tx_indexedsearch_pointer" class="hidden-inputs" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[ext]" class="hidden-inputs" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[type]" class="hidden-inputs" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[defOp]" class="hidden-inputs" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[media]" class="hidden-inputs" value="-1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[order]" class="hidden-inputs" value="rank_flag" />
            <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[group]" class="hidden-inputs" value="flat" />
            <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[lang]" class="hidden-inputs" value="-1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[desc]" class="hidden-inputs" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[results]" class="hidden-inputs" value="10" />
            <input type="submit" id="search-button" value="Suchen" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden-inputs {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    clear: left;
    margin-left: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#column1 {
    width: 245px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Hint: instead of adding classes to hidden inputs use CSS selector `input[type=hidden]`

Comment: I believe so as it's a CSS1 selector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is caused by empty text between `input.hidden-inputs`. You can fix it either by removing empty text between inputs or by setting `font-size:0;` for `form` element.

Examples:

1. `font-size` fix: http://jsfiddle.net/6fTHs/
2. Removing empty text: http://jsfiddle.net/keaukraine/BE7sV/

Answer (score 0):

The only way i know of to prevent it is to not have the hidden element in the dom.

If the "Value I want hidden" part is used purely for computational purposes, you should use the "data" attribute.

Like this

```
<div data-custom-value="1001">Visible value </div>
```

In jQuery, HTML data attributes are automatically available via the data() api.

You can do

```
someElement.data('customValue') to read a value.
```

and

```
someElement.data('customValue', newValue) to set a value.
```

Hope I analyzed your problem correctly.

Comment: The input fields are for a plugin in a CMS. I think it only accepts POST values. But it seems you are right. Don't using it is the only way. I think IE7 users will have to live with this design.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is probably a kludge like

```
form { word-spacing: -0.23em }
```

which reduces spacing between words inside the `form` by about the width of a space, or a little less. There are no words there, but IE 7 thinks there are – invisible words created by the hidden fields, separated by spaces.

A more robust solution is to remove the spaces around and between the hidden fields, as suggested by @keaukraine.